# Error trying to use OpenSSL .NET

Tags: c#, dll, openssl, dllimport

I've downloaded the lates version of the wrapper .NET for the OpenSSL from [openssl-net.sourceforge.net](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) Library but having troubles.

I tried to load a private.key like this:

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\SFDLL\private.key");
            OpenSSL.Core.BIO bio = new OpenSSL.Core.BIO(b);
            OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey key = OpenSSL.Crypto.CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(bio, "123123");
            int i = 0;
```

and got error:
[image: initializationOpenSSL.Core.Native exception]

and the Inner exception is

> {"Unable to load DLL 'libeay32': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}

**isn't this the correct way to do this? what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `libeay32` can't be found. As the installation instructions state on the link you posted for [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/):

> Installation
>
> Make sure you have libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll in the current
>   working directory of your application or in your PATH. In your .NET
>   project, add a reference to the ManagedOpenSsl.dll assembly.

So make sure you have a copy of that dll either in your build directory, or somewhere that is part of your system's PATH.

Comment: You were right, I had those dlls at the same place as the dll I've imported to the project I thought that was enough, but I updated the PATH with with the DLLs and I don't have that problem, but other different ones, Thanks.

Comment: You can add them as linked items to your project to get them to automatically copy to the bin\Debug (or bin\Release, or whatever other path you have configured) on build.

Comment: Make sure to install also Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable as stated in the "INSTALL" documentation: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999